# Silverlight about integer array

Tags: c#, silverlight

Basically, I want to create some images at random position, but each type of image must appears an even number of times. So I use an integer array to store the time of appearance of each image type. The problem is, I got an "System.IndexOutOfRange" exception when run the app. Blend for VS always highlight the lines of "MangRandom" array. Here is the code:

```
    int SoHinh = 0;
    string stt = "";
    int[] MangRandom = new int[4];
    public void CreateImage()
    {
        Image img1 = new Image();
        for (int i = 0; i < MangRandom.Length; i++)
        {
            if (MangRandom[i] % 2 != 0)
            {
                rand = i;
                break;
            }
            rand = GetRandInt(1, 5);
        } 
        img1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("item" + rand + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
        Canvas.SetLeft(img1, r.Next(0, 512));
        Canvas.SetTop(img1, r.Next(0, 546));
        if (SoHinh < 10) { stt = "0"; } else { stt = ""; }
        img1.Name = stt + SoHinh+"item" + rand + ".png";
        img1.Width = 32;
        img1.Height = 32;
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(img1);
        SoHinh++;
        MangRandom[rand] +=1;
    }
private void LayoutRoot_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        while (SoHinh <= 30)
        {
            CreateImage();

        }
    }
```

Am I doing anything wrong? How to fix this problem?

Comment: I fixed it myself. Increased MangRandom[4] to 5.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing `MangRandom[4]` to `5` solved the issue.